# Convert exponential string value to double - Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, double, exponential

I've an exponential string value

```
String str = "2.00000181334612E15";
```

And I'm trying to convert it to a double value.

```
Double d = (Double.parseDouble(str));
```

But am getting an Exception as follows,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:521)
    at com.swissre.lhrte.poi.test.TestClient.main(Test.java:133)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If line number 1047 is the `Double d = ...` line, then somehow `str` is NULL when it gets used there. Did you use a debugger to check?

Comment: Indeed. That's the stack trace I get if `str` is null, but when `str` is *actually* "2.00000181334612E15" it works fine. (This is why it's always worth providing a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...)

Comment: Just as an FYI, you also don't need the surrounding parenthesis. You can just do: `Double d = Double.parseDouble(str);`

Comment: Nope line number 133 is Double d = . . .

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 521... but regardless, as @JonSkeet mentioned, hard to figure this out without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Line 1047 is not in his code, neither is 521, I think you meant 133. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in your code. To see this, consider this code segment:

```
public class exp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "2.00000181334612E15";
    Double d = (Double.parseDouble(str));
    System.out.println(d);
  }
};
```

If you are getting a NullPointerException from Double.parseDouble then it means that you gave it a null argument. The code lines in your answer don't give it a null argument. So I guess in your full code you must be giving Double.parseDouble a null argument without you realizing it.

According to the Double.parseDouble() documentation, it calls Double.valueOf() and the documentation of Double.valueOf() specifies that you may give it exponential values.